# PHP - prepared statement bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are lots of other people having this issue but I cant find a solution. I've had this problem before and I managed to fix it:

```
$check = $conn->prepare("SELECT password,key,user FROM `users` WHERE email = ?");
$check->bind_param("s",$url_email); <-- line 31
$check->execute();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($check,$db_pass,$db_user_id,$db_username);  
$check->close();
```

But when using a prepared statement I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/login.php on line 31

Comment: `key` is reserved.

Comment: Your query also isn't selecting the userid, `$db_user_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're lucky. All your fields' names are [keywords or reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql.

You should escape them:

```
SELECT `password`, `key`, `user` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?
```

Strictly saying only `key` is a reserved word, `password` and `user` are not, but still escape'em.

Also, thanks to @chris85 you're mixing OO and procedural `mysqli`. Instead of

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($check,$db_pass,$db_user_id,$db_username);
```

use

```
$check->bind_result($db_pass, $db_user_id, $db_username);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but my problem still has not been solved. after using var_dump on the $url_email, its definitely a string,

Comment: While it's poor style to mix procedural with OO, it shouldn't cause an error AFAIK.